# How do I change this Javascript Regular Expression to be non-case sensitive?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression below to validate a security question where some one has to type in the answer twice. My client want the answers to be none case sensitive. So if someone types in Chester and the in the second field they type in chester it will match. What can I do to this expression to make that happen:

```
/^(\w|[a-zA-Z\d\s\.\@\-\?\,\&\/\_\#\+\(\)\""\'']){3,50}$/
```

Comment: Christ, I don't want to know what that expression matches! Edit, oh.. I guess its not so complicated after all. 3-50 of all the characters listed above? I think...

Comment: You can remove the redundancy of your regular expression and shorten it thusly: `/^[\w\s\.@\-\?,&\/#\+\(\)"']{3,50}$/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply append the `i` modifier:

```
/^(\w|[a-zA-Z\d\s\.\@\-\?\,\&\/\_\#\+\(\)\""\'']){3,50}$/i
```

Learn more about what the `i` modifier is and others [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression already is case insensitive... and redundant.  And that's all beside the point.  You want to compare two fields, there's nothing regular expressiony about that.  Here's your case insensitive field comparing function:

```
function fieldsMatch(input1, input2)
{
    return input1.value.toLowerCase() == input2.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can do it with a regular expression, if you insist.

function fieldsMatch(input1, input2){
    return /^([a-z\d\s\/.@?, &_#+()""''-]+)\1$/i.test(input1+ input2);
}

fieldsMatch('bone','BONE')


/*  returned value: (Boolean)
true
*/
```